# My python script stops working without any intervention

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to python and my script lasts about 3-4 hour and no error message is saved. What could be causing this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import time
import urllib.request
import threading

def load():
    try:
        content = str(urllib.request.urlopen("[URL]").read())
        # do sth with content
        threading.Timer(0.5, load).start()
    except Exception as e:
        file = open("Error.txt","w") 
        file.write(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S\n\n")) 
        file.write(e.message)
        file.close()
        threading.Timer(0.5, load).start()

def main(args):
    load()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

And here is nohup.out file on ubuntu 14.04:

```
Exception in thread Thread-907:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1182, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1125, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1163, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1121, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 951, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 886, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 863, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Comment: `Expection` ->  `Exception`. Typo, please close as such.

Comment: Please change file = open("Error.txt","w")  to file = open("Error.txt","a") mode.

Comment: The `logging` module would make more sense than manually opening a file

Comment: And `Network is unreachable` seems self-explanatory to me. The site refuses your request or your internet dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Network is unreachable` usually means you have a connectivity problem on your machine. Maybe it's an intermittent, short-lived problem, but you never try to detect it and recover from it.

Consider using something like [`retry` decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry), or handle it manually.

(I also find your way of looping the fetch logic rather bizarre. Why a simple single-threaded loop did not work for you?)